# How to use Google pub/sub service separately for test and release

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase

I'm using `pub/sub` for google `in-app purchase`.

After creating one `topic`, I created two `subscriptions`(push) (test server, release server).

After that, I added the topic I created to my app(rtdn).

However, the problem here is that tests and releases are not distinguished, so the messages used for testing are also sent to the release server.

So I'm curious. How can you separate the messages of test and release?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't see anything in the RTDN to see if it's a Sandbox or Production purchase.

However when validating purchase with androidpublisher API you can see if it's a test purchase.

If calling [purchases.subscriptionsv2](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptionsv2/get):

- Check testPurchase exists or not

If calling [purchases.subscriptions](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get):

- Check purchaseType